# merge 2 input values in url

Tags: php, url, query-string

I have form like this:

```
<form action="" method="get">
Color: <input type="text" name="color"><br>
Car: <input type="text" name="car"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

When i type color "red" and car "bmw" i get url like this

http://mywebsite/?color=red&car=bmw

**how can i get car array into color on submit so that it would be like this**

http://mywebsite/?color=red+bmw

Comment: use jquery ajax to take in the 2 form inputs asynchronously then combine them and submit the final submit using the concatenation of the inputs as one item.

Comment: You have asked a similar question recently. Please accept the answer to close your earlier question properly. If you have not received an answer, then update your question to refine it further based on the given answers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know of a way to modify the HTML form to produce that query string from two separate inputs. But in the PHP script that handles the form submission, the URL you're trying to get is basically the equivalent of this:

```
$_GET['color'] = implode(' ', $_GET);
unset($_GET['car']);
```

This will change `$_GET` to

```
array (size=1)
  'color' => string 'red bmw' (length=7)
```

as if you had submitted to

```
http://mywebsite/?color=red+bmw
```